# tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor in TF 2 API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

To my understanding tensorflow.contrib is removed in TF 2.0 API.  What's the new 2.0 alternative for tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor in TF 1.0 API? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/graph_editor

Answer (score 1):

The alternative as I understand from the documentation is the approach ["Keep track of your variables!"](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2#no_more_globals). When creating graph, you are now responsible for referencing it's nodes.